# Launch firefox browser on Android devices with Appium

Tags: appium, firefoxdriver, android-automation

I can not find a solution to launch firefox browser on Appium. I read the doc and do many research but it still doesn't work at all. The solution I try so far:

```
private AppiumDriver driver;
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Gecko");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "firefox");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_VERSION, "106");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "emulator-5554");
final Map<String, Object> firefoxOptions = new HashMap<>();
capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", firefoxOptions);

driver = new AndroidDriver("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", capabilities);
```

And the appium server response with that failure:

```
2022-10-28 04:21:01:695 [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1 ms - 68
2022-10-28 04:21:01:695 [HTTP] 
2022-10-28 04:21:02:088 [HTTP] Request idempotency key: bca5227e-ff58-4c45-8a4c-ef6fbe2d63bb
2022-10-28 04:21:02:097 [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
2022-10-28 04:21:02:097 [HTTP] {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"appium:automationName":"Gecko","appium:udid":"emulator-5554","browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"106","moz:firefoxOptions":{"androidPackage":"org.mozilla.firefox"},"platformName":"android"}}}
2022-10-28 04:21:02:097 [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"appium:automationName":"Gecko","appium:udid":"emulator-5554","browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"106","moz:firefoxOptions":{"androidPackage":"org.mozilla.firefox"},"platformName":"android"}}]
2022-10-28 04:21:02:098 [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1666930862097 (11:21:02 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time))
2022-10-28 04:21:02:115 [Appium] Appium v1.22.3 creating new GeckoDriver (v0.3.3) session
2022-10-28 04:21:02:116 [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
2022-10-28 04:21:02:116 [BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]     "browserName": "firefox",
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]     "browserVersion": "106",
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]     "moz:firefoxOptions": {
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]       "androidPackage": "org.mozilla.firefox"
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]     },
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]     "platformName": "android",
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]     "appium:automationName": "Gecko",
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]     "appium:udid": "emulator-5554"
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]   },
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]     {}
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver]   ]
2022-10-28 04:21:02:117 [BaseDriver] }
2022-10-28 04:21:02:119 [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: f3c3f9d6-9384-410b-8a53-98913db3468b
2022-10-28 04:21:02:135 [GeckoDriverServer] Starting 'C:\Users\SoNN\IdeaProjects\Ericsson_E2E_Mobile_Automation_Framework\browser_drivers\geckodriver.exe' with args ["-p",5200]
2022-10-28 04:21:02:144 [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2022-10-28 04:21:02:145 [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:5200/status] with no body
2022-10-28 04:21:02:152 [WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5200
2022-10-28 04:21:02:154 [GeckoDriverServer] [geckodriver.exe] 1666930862154 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:5200
2022-10-28 04:21:03:154 [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
2022-10-28 04:21:03:154 [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:5200/status] with no body
2022-10-28 04:21:03:157 [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"message":"","ready":true}}
2022-10-28 04:21:03:157 [WD Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
2022-10-28 04:21:03:157 [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:5200/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"106","moz:firefoxOptions":{"androidPackage":"org.mozilla.firefox"},"platformName":"android"}}}
2022-10-28 04:21:03:160 [WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"Unable to find a matching set of capabilities","stacktrace":""}}
2022-10-28 04:21:03:160 [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'session not created' to SessionNotCreatedError
2022-10-28 04:21:03:161 [GeckoDriver] Ending Gecko Driver session
2022-10-28 04:21:03:163 [GeckoDriverServer] geckodriver.exe has exited with code null, signal SIGTERM
2022-10-28 04:21:03:164 [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1666930863164 (11:21:03 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time))
2022-10-28 04:21:03:197 [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: SessionNotCreatedError: A new session could not be created. Details: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I just do not know what I am doing wrong. I finally come to desperation status after more than a week finding a really working solution. If anyone have any experience with automate firefox in android using Appium, please help me. You can become my hero and save my day and get a coffee from me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability("appPackage", "org.mozilla.firefox");
dc.setCapability("appActivity", ".App");
```